# Unable to restore dump file in mysql5.5

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to restore a mysql5.5 dump file using mysql command prompt using the command given below:

```
mysql> -u <username> -p <password> <dbname> < <dumpfile>
```

But it is giving the below error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`-u ro
>   ot -p password mydb< "D:\mysql_dump\backup_2013_01_mydb.sql"`' at line 1

Please help. I've tried it on both WinXP and Win7.
Also please guide how to do the same using Mysql Workbench.

Comment: On line 1?  Did you dump from a Linux system and are restoring to a Windows one?  Do you need to convert line endings?  I'm not sure if that matters, but "line 1" seems suspicious.  Otherwise, what *is* on line 1?

Comment: Hi Mat, the dump is also taken from windows system.

Comment: What version of mysql was on the Windows box? Did you dump usign `--all databases` or did you dump a specific database ?

Comment: we are using mysql5.5 and we created the dump for a specific database. The cmd we are using is: set DATET=%date:~-4%_%date:~7,2%
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqldump" --host=localhost --user=root --password=root123 mydb >"d:\mysql_dump\"backup_%DATET%_mydb.sql 
pause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the link below for the answer.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36043/20734

Thank You