# How to restore mysql dump file?

Tags: mysql-5.5, mysqldump

We have created a dump file (.sql) using the command mysqldump in mysql5.5.
Now we want to restore the same. We are using the command :-

`-u[username] -p[pwd] [dbname] < [.sql file]`

But we are not able to restore.
We are using Win7 SP1 32 bit OS.

Comment: You are using `mysql` to restore the dump created by `mysqldump`? If so, do you get an error?

Comment: @PaulWhite I've closed that one in favour of this because Neeru said it had been answered here. Neeru please tick the answer that helped you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got solved by using command prompt of Windows OS. Following are the steps:

1. Change the directory to the one where your dump file is residing.

   ```
   cd /d [pathname]
   ```
2. Execute the restore command

   ```
   mysql -u[username] -p[password] [dbname] < [filename]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you left part of your command off.  To be clear, you'll need to use the mysql client for the import.  But, in general that should work.  Another option is to just connect to the client (same command as before, but with out the the

Once in you can run

```
mysql> source /path/to/outfile.sql
```